# wx.TE_PROCESS_ENTER event produces nothing

Tags: python, wxpython

For some reason nothing is happening when I press the enter button. Ive looked at the Documents and have done all it has recommended

```py
        self.text_ctrl_ = wx.SearchCtrl(self.panel_1,style=wx.TE_PROCESS_ENTER)
        self.text_ctrl_.ShowCancelButton(True)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_TEXT_ENTER, self.on_text_enter, self.text_ctrl_)
        self.text_ctrl_.AutoComplete(choices)
```

here is my function

```py
def on_text_enter(self,event):
        print('working')
        pass
```

Comment: you could show minimal working code so we could run it, see problem and test ideas.

Comment: Bind to directly to `self.text_ctrl_` not via `self` i.e. `self.text_ctrl_.Bind(wx.EVT_TEXT_ENTER, self.on_text_enter)`